# How to move from insert to replace/overtype mode in vim

Tags: vim, vimrc, macvim

How can you switch from insert mode to replace/overtype mode in vim?
In windows/*nix I just hit the insert key twice (command->insert->replace), but unfortunately i'm stuck on a mac now which doesn't recognize the insert key.

Comment: Why can't you hit Esc to go to Normal mode and then type R to go into replace mode? (See [Vim Modes](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/vim/modes/))

Comment: Its what I'm doing now but it I would like to add some remaps to be able to just hit a toggle key, force of habit with a standard keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can map a key combination to do the role of the "Insert" key while in insert mode.

For instance, to use Control-T:

```
:inoremap <C-T> <Ins>
```